# Differential Equation $dy/dx=y^{1/3}$ and condition $y(x_0)=y_0$ has infinite solutions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Prove that the differential equation 
>   $$\frac{dy}{dx}= y^{1/3}$$
>   with the initial value of $y(x_0)=y_0$ has infinite solutions.

I don't really understand the problem if I have to show that there are infinite solutions depending on the initial conditions or if it is something like if I proposed $(x_0,y_0)=(0,0)$ and prove that for that case the equation has infinite solutions. if you think is the first one could you explain how to do it.

Comment: i have read somewhere that $\frac{dy}{dx}=y^{\alpha}$ conditon $y(x_0)=0$ has infinite solution when $1>\alpha$

Comment: [Wolfie](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=dy%2Fdx+%3D+y%5E%281%2F3%29)

Comment: Define "has infinite solutions". Does it mean that it blows up? Or that it has infinitely many solutions?

Answer (score 5):

If $y_0 > 0$ then $f(y) = y^{1/3}$ is Lipschitz in a neighbourhood of $y_0$ (the derivative is bounded). So by Picard-Lindelöf there is a unique solution.

On the other hand, for $y_0 = 0$, $f$ is no longer Lipschitz and so we can no longer expect a unique solution. In fact two solutions are found readily:

$$ y(x) = 0 \text{ and } y(x) = \left[\frac{2}{3}(x - x_0)\right]^{3/2}. $$

But as Wikipedia alludes to in its article on the [Peano existence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_existence_theorem#Related_theorems), the transition between the two solutions can happen at any point (not just at $x_0$). So the general solution is

$$ y_a(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & x \le a, \\
\left[\frac{2}{3}(x - a)\right]^{3/2} & x > a,
\end{cases} $$

for any parameter $a \ge x_0$.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{dy}{dx} = y^ \frac{1}{3} $ , by using method of variable separable we will get $y(x)= \left(\frac{2x}{3}+k\right)^\frac{3}{2}$ ; where $k$ is an arbitrary constant now consider $x_0 = 0$ and $y_0 = 0$ as  initial conditions then for every $\alpha \ge0$ we have $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x \le\alpha \\ \left(\frac{2x}{3}-\frac{2\alpha}{3}\right)^\frac{3}{2}, & x\gt\alpha \end{cases}$$ so uncountably infinite solution for this initial condition.

Answer (score -1):

With $$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \sqrt[3]{y} \quad y(x_{0}) = y_{0}$$ then 
\begin{align}
y^{-1/3} \, dy &= dx \\
\frac{3}{2} \, y^{2/3} &= x + c_{0} \\
y(x) &= \left[ \frac{2}{3} \, (x + c_{0}) \right]^{3/2}.
\end{align}

When $y(x_{0}) = y_{0}$ then
$$c_{0} = \frac{3}{2} \, y_{0}^{2/3} - x_{0}$$
and
$$ y(x) = \left[ \frac{2}{3} \, (x - x_{0}) + \sqrt[3]{y_{0}} \right]^{3/2}. $$